# How to return a string instead of PY_VAR

Tags: python, tkinter, timer

HELP!  Still learning Python here. Why am I getting PY_VAR1 returned instead of the string in "QUOTE1" (in an external file). And, is there any way to clear the screen for the next instance to display.  As of right now, the quotes keep stacking on top of each other instead of presenting one at a time. Thank you for the help!

```
def updateQuote(self):
    self.quoteNumber = 1

    if (self.quoteNumber <=10):
        quote = "QUOTE"+str(self.quoteNumber)
        self.quote=StringVar()
        self.quote.set(self.quote)
        self.msg = Message(self.window,textvariable=self.quote,
                           width=300,font=("Aria",24))
        self.quoteNumber+=1
            
        self.msg.pack(side=TOP)

        self.window.after(3000,self.updateQuote)
```

Comment: Try searching this site for `PY_VAR0`

Comment: Should be `self.quote.set(quote)`.

Answer (score 1):

`PY_VAR1` is shown because `self.quote` is passed to `self.quote.set()`.  `quote` should be used instead.

In order to show only one instance of quote, `self.msg` should be created once and update its text inside `updateQuote()` via `self.quote`.

Also you should not reset `self.quoteNumber` to 1 in every run of `updateQuote()`.

```
def __init__(self):
    ...
    # moved from self.updateQuote()
    self.quote = StringVar()
    self.msg = Message(self.window, textvariable=self.quote, width=300, font=("Aria",24))
    self.msg.pack(side=TOP)
    ...
    # start the quote display
    self.updateQuote()

def updateQuote(self, quoteNumber=1):
    if quoteNumber <= 10:
        quote = "QUOTE" + str(quoteNumber)
        self.quote.set(quote) # update self.msg
        self.window.after(3000, self.updateQuote, quoteNumber+1)
```